# Google Map - Onclick re-render (height bug)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, click, rendering

I have a working google map via JS with custom styles. I am looking to use this twice on the site, however with a fixed element, the element is set @ 0px then transitions to 800px in height. However I need to call the google resize event in order for the map to re-size otherwize it results in a bad UI (clipped map).

[image]

Resize Code:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

I have the following code:

```
function google_map_custom(){
    function GoogleMapOptions(){
        var markerPosition = new google.maps.LatLng([variable],[variable]),
            mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng([variable],[variable]);

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            scrollwheel: false,
            panControl:true,
            zoomControl:true,
            rotateControl:true,
            disableDefaultUI:true,
            center: mapCenter,
            styles: [
                {
                    "CUSTOM Google JSON": "styles"
                },
            {}]

        };

        // ASSOCIATE VARIABLE WITH HTML ID
        var mapElement = document.getElementById('google-map');
        // Align Settings to DOM Element
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

        // RETINA MARKER (CUSTOM RE-SIZE) - USE VARIABLE BELOW
        var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage("[path-to-url]", null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(44,65));

        // Tailor Custom Marker (SVG / PNG ACCEPTED) - USE CDN
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: markerPosition,
            map: map,
            icon:image
        });
    }
    // Trigger map with element id and specific settings above
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', GoogleMapOptions);
}
```

My question is, how do I call the resize event on a click handler? I have this code as an example:

```
    $('[class selector]').click(function(){
        $('#google-map.hidden--homepage').toggleClass('[active selector 800px in height]');

       // INVOKE FUNCTION
        google_map_custom();
    });
```

Just to confirm, transition works, styles work, map loads. I just need to trigger the map when the element is enlarged.

thanks!

COMMENT IMG (this is the styles for the google container:

[image]

Comment: I think you are basically answering your own question!  `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');` needs to be called when whatever animation/transition/resize is completed, just make sure you are passing a global reference to `map` and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks @RobSchmuecker I know what you mean :) I just don't know how to implement this event trigger. Do you have a code example?

Comment: Please show the code that is transitioning your window from 0 to 800px.

Comment: Your code doesn't work as posted.  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/keg8tj63/) that displays a map on click (doesn't change the size of the div, as your code doesn't do that).

Comment: The toggle is controlled using .toggleClass the animation and height is controlled using css. When clicked it removes a class and has a linear transition already present. The js creates the map the jquery just toggles a class and calls the function. At present the page loads and renders the map (hidden with a height of 0) I want to load the map on click.

Comment: The call of `google_map_custom()` inside the `click`-callback will not do anything, because inside `google_map_custom` you never call `GoogleMapOptions` (this function runs only 1 time, when the load-event of the window fires)

Comment: I fixed this by running the function on doc load, and setting the height @ 800px, the with the parent container clipping the map while having an animation. @Dr.Molle how would you have coded the function to load on click?

Comment: basically there is no need for the outer function(`google_map_custom`). There is also no need to load the map on click(when you see the map you must have called `google_map_custom` somewhere else earlier). Related to the resize-issue: It's not clear where you run the click-function, but your map-variable is only visible inside `GoogleMapOptions` , so triggering the resize-event of `map` will not work outside of this function. You may trigger the resize-event of `window` instead.

Comment: @Dr.Molle that makes complete sense now. How would you write the code for the resize-event? I would need to fire ideally when the container is opened.. Would this be used via .toggleClass then .done().promise(function(){...})?

Comment: Take a look at [`transitionend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend)